# can we move out of sandbox mode in aws SES domain without need of dedicated IP (using only shared IP)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm new to AWS SES, forgive me if my question is childish. We can only send emails from verified domain or email in AWS SES. To move out of sandbox mode we need to contact AWS support. My question is: can we move out of sand box mode with shared IP address? I need to move my domain verification out of sand box mode, but I don't want any extra charging which means I don't need dedicated IP for this.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move out of the SES sandbox without the need to purchase any [dedicated IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dedicated-ips.html).

See [Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).

Comment: If I need a dedicated IP , What will I do At the time of sending limit increase request? @Khalid T

Comment: @ArunKumar Using the **Use Case Description**, state that you want to request dedicated IP addresses, and indicate the number of dedicated IP addresses that you are requesting. See [Requesting Dedicated IP Addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dedicated-ip-case.html#dedicated-ip-case-request)